# Can not mount old encrypted home partition

Tags: release-freya, startup, boot

Computer: Acer Aspire 4752
Intel core i3-2330M, 6GB RAM,500GB HDD

I had the 64-bit elementary OS Luna with the following disk partitions:

1. /dev/sda1(400GB) as /home
2. /dev/sda2(30GB) as /root
3. /dev/sda3(5gb) as swap
4. /dev/sda4 as boot(efi?)

Rest as unallocated space, I installed elementary OS Freya (64bit) using the "something else" option and leaving my home partition **as is**. Now when I boot I am stuck at this screen:

[image]

I tried the manual recovery but can't get any further than this:

[image]

Now I tried pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, the black screen then says `Warning : Fake initcl called`, doing nothing . Well, nothing happens and I have to force shutdown, running `startx` doesn't help either just a completely blank screen appears. This is my primary computer and I don't have anything to backup my data to, any solution which doesn't have the risk of loosing my data would save my day.

PS: I used the same username and login password as before. Now would be investing in an external HDD.

Comment: Linux has two unrelated encryption mechanisms: [dm-crypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dm-crypt), for full-disk encryption, which is what your swap space uses, and [ecryptfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECryptfs), for per-directory encryption, which is what you use for your personal files. That's a sensible combination, but it seems that something went wrong with the installation. This *may* warrant a bug report, but you need to describe exactly how you did the installation and what the current state of your system is.

Comment: Edit your question to the output of the shell commands `cat /etc/fstab` and `cat /etc/crypttab` and `lsblk` . Did you mention anything about encryption during installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to *solve* my issue by re-installing and **not** using swap at all, as I have a 6GB of physical memory.The encrypted home partition is now mounted by default and everything works fine barring a few glitches here and there.

I now am facing entirely new issues related to lightdm and elementary desktop which require a new question.
It's not *actually* a solution because the problem I had was rather interesting might have taught something new to me.